# fetching data from database in input field using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a database table named "reg". Many fields are there. Among them two fields are Name & ID. I want to fetch particular ID by selecting Name from select box. I just know ajax is appropriate for that but I did not work with ajax. If anyone kindly help this, it would better for me.

```
<label for="id">Instructor Name:</label><br>
     <select class="form-control input-sm" name="categories" id="sel3">
                <?php 
         $sql_sel = "SELECT * FROM reg WHERE Dept = '$Department' and Type !='Student' and Activity= 'Y' ";
         $result_sel = mysqli_query($con,$sql_sel);
         while ($row_sel = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sel)){
                ?>
         <option value='<?php echo $row_sel["Name"]; ?>'>
         <?php echo $row_sel['Name']; ?>
         </option>
                <?php
              }
                ?>                      
    </select>

   <label for="id">Instructor ID:</label><br>
   <input class="form-control input-sm" name="Instructor_id" id="inputsm" type="text" required>
```

Comment: You need help in implementing this by using ajax ?

Comment: `  <option value='<?php echo $row_sel["ID"]; ?>'>
         <?php echo $row_sel['Name']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

assign fetched name id to select box value 
then on change of select call ajax ie. get -> fetchdata.php (it will return user data)

then in ajax success(data) you will have data as fetched value

Answer (score 0):

You should modularize ur php-code to a rest-api type entity. This is called separation of concerns, and keeps server side code and UI code separate. It also helps in Test Driven Development as well.

Jquery obj provides the .ajax() method which can be used here.
Jquery.ajax() -or- $.ajax() can be used.

So, you can do something like this:-

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/path/to/rest/api", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would usually suggest Ajax.But If you don't want to use ajax in your code, this is the answer for you

Your code should be something along the lines of this:

```
function foo() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "/custom/custom_url");
    httpRequest.send();
    return httpRequest.responseText;
}

var result = foo(); // always ends up being 'undefined'
```

> XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is an API that can be used by JavaScript,
>   JScript, VBScript, and other web browser scripting languages to
>   transfer and manipulate XML data to and from a webserver using HTTP,
>   establishing an independent connection channel between a webpage's
>   Client-Side and Server-Side.

**OR**

You could use something like this

**$.getJSON**

```
$.getJSON( '/custom/custom_url', { data1:"123", data2:"234"})
  .done( function(resp){
    // handle response here
}).fail(function(){
   alert('Oooops');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="categories" id="sel3">
<?php
    $select = $con->query("SELECT * FROM reg WHERE Dept='$Department'AND Type!='Student' AND Activity='Y'");
    while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <option value='<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>'><?php echo $row["Name"];?></option>
<?php } ?>                
</select>
```

Are you sure about field names? my opinion is that use simple characters to field names.